# Issue with merging and reordering two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reorderlist

I'm trying to figure out how to merge two arrays of objects. Here's what I need to do:

- `field` property is the unique identifier of each object
- Output needs to only have the objects listed in the `originalArray`, including objects in `originalArray` that do not exist in `localStorageArray`
- Order of `localStorageArray` needs to be maintained, with attention paid to previous requirement (order should be: `bar`, `bee`, `foo`, `baz`)
- Output needs to contain the following property values from `localStorageArray`: `hidden` and `width` (`field` is a give-in, since its the identifier)
- All other properties of `originalArray` need to be maintained in output

Here's my wack at it:

```
var outputArray = [];

localStorageArray.forEach(function(localItem){
    originalArray.forEach(function(originalItem){
        if(originalItem.field === localItem.field){
            var item = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalItem));
            item.hidden = localItem.hidden;
            item.width = localItem.width;
            outputArray.push(item);
        }
    });
});
```

## [Full JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/wncgqkdw/)

I was able to get the ordering correct and the properties right, but one issue I'm having is when a object exists in `originalArray` that doesn't exist in `localStorageArray`, that object is not included in the `outputArray`.

Any suggestions to my solution?

Here are my arrays:

```
var originalArray = [
    {field: "foo", hidden: true, sortable: false, template: "<div>#=text#</div>", width: "20px", propA: "a", propB: "b"},
    {field: "bee", hidden: true, sortable: false, template: "=#text#", int: 4},
    {field: "bar", hidden: false, sortable: false, template: "", width: "20%", propC: "C"},
    {field: "baz", hidden: false, sortable: true, template: "<span>#=text#</span>", int: 3}
];

var localStorageArray = [
    {field: "bar", hidden: false, sortable: false, width: "100px"},
    {field: "foo", hidden: true, sortable: false, template: "<div>#=text#</div>", width: "40px"},
    {field: "boo", hidden: true, sortable: true, template: "<div>Boo: #=text#</div>", width: "200px"},
    {field: "baz", hidden: true, template: "baz:#=text#", width: "20px"}
];
```

And here is my desired output:

```
var desiredArray =  [
   {field: "bar", hidden: false, sortable: false, template: "", width: "100px", propC: "C"},
   {field: "bee", hidden: true, sortable: false, template: "=#text#", int: 4},
   {field: "foo", hidden: true, sortable: false, template: "<div>#=text#</div>", width: "40px", propA: "a", propB: "b"},
   {field: "baz", hidden: true, sortable: true, template: "<span>#=text#</span>", width: "20px", int: 3}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to overwrite the `hidden` and `width` properties of those objects in `originalArray` that are also present in `localStorageArray` (2 objects are considered the same if `field` property is the same)

```
    (function () {
    var fieldArray = localStorageArray.map(function(e) { return e.field; });
    originalArray.forEach(function(originalItem) {
      var index = fieldArray.indexOf(originalItem.field);
      var localItem; 
      if(index !== -1) {
        //it's also in localStorage, overwrite 
        localItem = localStorageArray[index];
        originalItem.hidden = localItem.hidden || originalItem.hidden;
        originalItem.width = localItem.width || originalItem.width;
        outputArray.push(originalItem);
      }
    })();
```

Instead of creating an additional array, you can also loop through localStorageArray and compare the `field` property

Comment: Also, if you need to keep originalArray as it was, create a new object and push that to outputArray